# How to migrate content from non sxa sitecore 8.2 to SXA based sitecore 10.2 version?

Tags: content-migration

We have completely redesigned a traditional Sitecore 8.2 based website to Sitecore 10.2 with SXA. Now, we want to move the content from 8.2 to 10.2 in a way that if

1. A page in 8.2 has a different field name, based on a particular template, and the same page has a different field in 10.2, based on a particular template.
2. In 8.2 the data source items are available at different locations, somewhere in the global folder outside the Home Node, and in 10.2 SXA we have already a Data folder where we have already predefined parents folder available for each page-specific content.

I know that I will have to write custom logic for content migration but need your thoughts on what could be possible best approaches to achieve this migration.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the approach you can take to migrate the data from `8.2` to `10.2`

- Install `Sitecore vanilla` with `SXA`.
- Download the production master database
- Use `RAZL` to copy custom templates, Layouts, and content to `Sitecore 10.2`
- Use `RAZL` to copy content items (data sources) for each component from the old site to `Sitecore 10.2` SXA data folder
- Identify the components which can be `SXA components`. Find those component templates and map those fields to SXA fields.
- Run a `PowerShell` script to transform the old template to the SXA template.
- Tweak the script to create the folder structure.
- Repeat the step above for all the components.

Use the below article for the migration steps.

https://www.konabos.com/blog/lift-and-shift-to-sitecore-sxa-migration-the-easy-way

And finally, you need to create your Custom `PowerShell` script to move the data into the appropriate location.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is the one you are familiar.
I recommend you to use Sitecore Powershell extension is a very flexible solution, really easy to implement it.

Have a look on PSE how to work with Sitecore items: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items